# Android Listview items click

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter, listviewitem

I have a listview with a custom BaseAdapter that fills listview items from json/internet.

In each listview item i have a pseudo buttons(FrameLayouts) with on click event attached to them. When "MAYBE" is clicked for example, I make a call to a server and change event status to "Maybe". After call comes back with success, I would like to change FrameLayouts background to appropriate color (Orange for Maybe).

Where i am having difficulty is to reference other/neighboring FrameLayouts so i can change their backgrounds to "neutral".

[image]

All of my events are in BaseAdapter and i set onClick event in GetView method.

My question is: Is there a better way/ how to setup onclick event for each FrameLayout so clicked FrameLayout is aware on click event of other neighboring FrameLayouts so i can change their background to neutral and selected background to respected color.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your XML add theese attibutes to your FrameLayout(Button)

```
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="onMaybeClick"
```

Then in your baseAdapter `getView()` method you find the FrameLayout by

```
FrameLayout maybeBtn = (FrameLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_maybe_btn);
maybeBtn.setTag(4257 + postion);
```

You can also set the `maybeBtn` onClickable in the `getView()` instead of XML, the same goes for the clicklistener.

In your activity you can the create a `onButtonClick(View v)` method

```
public void onMaybeClick(View v)
{
   int position = (Integer)((FrameLayout)v).getTag() - 4257; //To get the position of the click

   LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();

   FrameLayout btnYes = (FrameLayout)parent.getChildAt(0); //first button
   FrameLayout btnNo = (FrameLayout)parent.getChildAt(2); //second button

   ServerCallback(new requestListener(){
       ifSuccess(){
           v.setBackground(...);
       }
   ]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I already pass the position in the TAG. But (View v) will be reference to the clicked FrameLayout. How can i get a hold of neighboring FrameLayouts so i can change their backgrounds as well. Thanks!

Comment: Oh oh i see. but then why would we need position then? let me try this out and i will award the answer if this works. Thanks!

Comment: Because you probably have an `mArray` with information that fills the List, you want to know the position of the item so you can for example pass `mArray.get(position).getId` as a parameter to the server to know  which item is clicked Yes/No/Maybe (The clicked item information)

Comment: correct, but i was passing itemId in the Tag as well. Thanks. Trying it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a selector to manipulate the state of the view

1) Create a selector to set the colors and states

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
       <item android:drawable="@android:color/black" android:state_selected="false"/>
       <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_selected="true"/>
   </selector>
```

2) On background set the selector

```
<FrameLayout 
    ...      
       android:clickable="true"
       android:background="@drawable/selector_view">
   </FrameLayout>
```

3) In the code part try to play with this

```
@Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       view.setSelected(true);
       ...
   }
```

Comment: Thats a good idea, i would need 3 selectors for each FrameLayout's then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do this inside your `adapter` `getView()` method. So it is going to applied to all the `ListView` items currently on `View`

```
// change the row color based on selected position
if(selectedItem == position){
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
else
{
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Comment: i do not want to reload items from the server. Yes, it is the easiest way to refresh data from the Internet, and all FrameLayouts will have correct background. My intent to change the background without the refresh.

Comment: This doesn't refresh if you have `ViewHolder` implemented properly inside your adapter `getView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Register the same `onClickListener()` for every item in the row.

Implement the `onClickListener()` to the `BaseAdapter` class, and place logic there in such a way that if MAYBE was clicked, loop every `List<Item> itemList` of your `ListView`, set a boolean value (for example `otherSelected`) to true for each one of them, then `invalidate()` the `ListView`, and make sure that for the `getView()` callback you handle those Items with `otherSelected` set to true, and change their view background before returning them.